# Creating msi from different exe and jar files

Tags: windows-installer

I have an application which includes some .exe and jar files, i need to create a single installation file which will install all files and create an shortcut to my jar file..

Can anybody help, how to do this?? I have no idea about it...

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous tools you can use to create MSI files.

- [Wix](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) is bundled with recent versions of Visual Studio and is also available as an independent suite. Generates MSI files from xml descriptions (free).
- [Nsis](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) uses its own description language and has at least one example demonstrating Java support (never tried it, free).
- [InstallShield](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installshield.htm) (commercial).
- and surely others...

Comment: Thanks, i tried Nsis.. but prob is it simply copys my files to specified location, i want to create an msi which will setup (execute) all .exe files..